# dynamically select on IP address from two NICs based on user input with java, and demo connection

Tags: java, networking, ip, user-input, nic

I have the following sample code. What I would like to achieve is to be able to dynamically select which IP address to connect to from two different choices, I want to be able to select this based on user input, but I don't exactly know how to achieve that.

I have a strong suspicion that it should use the Socket() method constructor, specifically the first instance that has a [signature with 4 arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29)
which should allow you to specify using the public Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int LocalPort) throws IOException method, you can use the third parameter to specify which IP Address to use.

I've also heard good things about the bind() method

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import static java.lang.System.out;

 public class ListNets {

public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
        displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
}

static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
    out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
    out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
    for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
        out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
    }
    out.printf("\n");
 }
 }
```

That code up top spits out the IP addresses, but it also returns a bunch of "useless" information, such as ethernet address which i don't want, how to isolate just the IP addresses I'm interested in?

Also, what is an effective way to demonstrate my IP address? Maybe connect to whois.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That code up top spits out the IP addresses, but it also returns a bunch of "useless" information, such as ethernet address which i don't want, how to isolate just the IP addresses I'm interested in?

Simple. Don't print anything *except* the IP addresses. Remove the code that prints anything else.

As for your 'strong suspicion', you've been *told* in two separate previous questions that you should use the four-argument `Socket` constructor.

Comment: exactly right, and I have thereby cultivated a very strong suspicion indeed!

Comment: but more to the point, I tried to comment out all that garbage but it no use, I still get a bunch of useless crap, I tried something like this, but alas... not effective!
if (inetAddress == SOMETHING?!)

Comment: dude- please help me! i know it is within your power!